# Data Transformation in Power Query

Tags: excel, transformation, powerquery

I have the below data table (simplified):

[image]

I need to transform the data in such a way to get the below format:

[image]

I have very limited knowledge of M language, as such I have been trying to use the tools provided within the Query Editor. I have tried using variations of Transpose, Unpivot etc. but I seemingly can't seem to solve this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unpivot the columns, except for the first one:

[image: 1]

This is the result:

[image: 2]